# Flutter: How to create a row with a centered word with a line around it?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Trying to accomplish the below effect:

[image: The word OR with 2 horizontal lines around it]

This is the code I have:

```
            new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Divider(
                      color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                      height: 20
                  ),
                  new Text(
                    "OR",
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Divider(
                      color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                      height: 20
                  ),
                ]),
```

The word OR appears in the middle but both Dividers are hidden? (However, if I play with the height you can see the height of the row increase/decrease but still no divider. How can I get this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this widget, it will do exactly what you want

```
class OrComponent extends StatelessWidget {


   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return Row(
         children: <Widget>[
           Expanded(
             child: Container(
               height: 2.0,
               color: AppColor.lighterGrey,
             ),
           ),
        Container(
           margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.0),
           child: Text("OR",style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black)),
        ),
        Expanded(
           child: Container(
             height: 2.0,
             color: Colors.grey,
        ),
       ),
      ],
    );
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Expanded`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget on the two Dividers (and on the Text for coherence purposes)

```
Expanded(
  flex: 1,
  child: Divider(
      color: const Color(0xFF000000),
              height: 2,
 )),
 Expanded(
      flex: 0,
       child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "OR",
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                    ),
 ))),
 Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Divider(
                color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                height: 2,
 ))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, I just had to wrap it in a Row but that worked.